# SQLite: Add column or rows first?

Tags: database-design, sqlite

I have a SQLite table that needs a a couple of columns and about a million rows added.

Is it faster to add the columns and then the rows, or the rows and then the columns?

Both the columns and the rows are primarily null values. At a later point I'll be using another script to populate them with data.

Update: The Sqlite docs say: "AlterTable runs as fast on a table with 1 row as it does with 10M rows" (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

So my question is actually:

*Does adding rows slow down with more columns?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are adding a new column to a table, SQLite does not change the table data itself.
If a table record has less column than the table definition, the missing columns are assumed to be NULL. A table record get written with the full number of columns when an UPDATE affects that record (or when you INSERT a new record).

Therefore, adding empty records before adding the columns will write less data to the database. (It's possibly that the difference is too small to be noticeable.)

However, the biggest performance problem probably is the updating of the records later.
If at all possible, you should insert the records with their final data, and avoid updating them.

Answer (score 0):

Start a transaction, then add the rows, and commit the transaction. Otherwise Sqlite will try to commit to disk after each insert, causing it to be much slower.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of transactions, my question is just whether it's faster to add the rows first or the columns first.